# Flexigrid getting ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexigrid

I am using flexigrid that calls php page to get data. On success i want to get ajax response data but it is returning html object of the flexigrid. How can i get response json?

Here is the code

```
$('.flexme').flexigrid({
    url: 'data.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    colModel: <? php echo $this - > gridcols; ?> ,
    striped: false,
    width: 942,
    height: 'auto',
    showToggleBtn: false,
    useRp: true,
    rp: 15,
    usepager: true,
    onSubmit: addFormData,
    showTableToggleBtn: true,
    onError: function (data) {
        alert("Error occured");
    },
    onSuccess: function (statusdata) {
        console.log(statusdata);
    },
    preProcess: function(responsedata){
        console.log(responsedata)
    }
});
```

Here statusdata contains html for the grid not json from the URL.

Update:

Use

```
preProcess:function (jsondata) {
console.log(jsondata);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Just something to make clear, function preProcess must return a processed data. If you don't return data, flexigrid will display an connection error.

```
   function preProcessData(data) {
    /*do something with data*/
    return data;
}
```

taken from here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/flexigrid/y6c76Np2Xjw